# Displayport MST not working properly on Xubuntu 15.04

Tags: xubuntu, 15.04, multiple-monitors, display, displayport

In several questions on this site, I saw that Ubuntu 15.04 would have support for Displayport daisychaining/MST.  I have a two monitors that have Displayport in and out, indicating that they can be connected together.  When connected to my laptop, both monitors work, but only one display appears, and that display is mirrored over both monitors.

I am using integrated Intel graphics on a Dell XPS 13.  I had to install Xubuntu over a Windows installation.

Any ideas about what I have to do to get Xubuntu to detect the daisychained monitor?

EDIT:

System information:

- Graphics card (from `lspci -nn`): VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616] (rev 09)
- CPU (from `cat /proc/cpuinfo`): model name   : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
- Monitor Model: Dell U2713Hb

Comment: Which exact Intel graphics processor do you have? Please specify the processor model your XPS 13 has. Also please mention which model of displays you have.

Comment: @gertvdijk added the requested information

Comment: I happen to own the same Dell display and it only has one displayport port. Are you sure that's the right model? Displays capable of daisychaining are quite rare. Also, usually U-processors support the maximum of 2560x1440 resolution and don't offer 4k-bandwidth support. However, your Broadwell hardware might be the first generation of Intel graphics to do that. It may be that the graphics drivers in the Linux kernel + Xorg don't yet support this because of the relatively new hardware.